# How can I add a badge next to the title of a panel?

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am using BootsFaces in version 0.7.0.

In BootsFaces, you can easily create a badge with `<b:badge value="#{bean.size}"/>`. This works great.

Actually I am using a `<b:panel title="Authors"/>`.

[image: Panel]

I am trying to add a `<b:badge/>` just next to the title (As you can see in the image). Is there any possibility to achieve this with BootsFaces or is there a nice way in CSS?
Have you other hints for using this, specially for user XP?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then try this : `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <span class="badge">7</span></button>`

Comment: If in `BootsFaces` there's no option then using `position` property of `CSS` you can set your badge on panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the title of the `<b:panel>` by a `heading` facet:

```
<b:panel>
  <f:facet name="heading">
    <h:outputText value="Panel heading with a facet in place of a title "/>
    <b:badge style="margin-left:10px" value="since version 0.4"/>
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="Panel Content"/>
</b:panel>
```

(Note that the `style` attribute of `<b:badge>` is a feature of BootsFaces 0.8.0).

[image]

Comment: Those spacing can be done with `<p:spacer height="1px" width="10px"></p:spacer>` until the new version is up (can not wait!).